# Shell mode - clear screen but keep scrollback

Tags: shell, comint

When using a normal terminal application (like Konsole, for example), I regularly use `Control-L` or the `clear` command to clear the terminal's contents, leaving the cursor on the top. When I do this, I can still scroll up and read the output of the commands I ran previously (they are not discarded).

In Emacs shell mode (`M-x shell`), I've been using `comint-clear-buffer` to clear the contents of the terminal and leave the point (and prompt) on the top. The problem with this command is that it also discards the output of all the commands I have run up to that moment. Using `recenter-top-bottom` doesn't help, because when I use it to position the point and prompt at the top, as soon as I input a command and hit `ENTER`, the point 'jumps' back to its original position.

The question I would like to ask is: is there a command similar to `comint-clear-buffer` that doesn't discard the output of previous commands?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45281/16300
this might solve your problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom` in the hook `comint-output-filter-functions` is causing to scroll to bottom and so to remove it from the hook add this snippet to emacs config

```
(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook
          (defun rm-comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom ()
            (remove-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
                         'comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom)))
```

after this you can use `C-l C-l` to clear screen in shell and proceed with any commands without scroll